# Python: .append(0)

Tags: python

I would like to ask what the following does in Python.
It was taken from http://danieljlewis.org/files/2010/06/Jenks.pdf

I have entered comments telling what I think is happening there.

```
# Seems to be a function that returns a float vector
# dataList seems to be a vector of flat. 
# numClass seems to an int

def getJenksBreaks( dataList, numClass ):

    # dataList seems to be a vector of float. "Sort" seems to sort it ascendingly
    dataList.sort() 

    # create a 1-dimensional vector 
    mat1 = []

    # "in range" seems to be something like "for i = 0 to len(dataList)+1)
    for i in range(0,len(dataList)+1):

        # create a 1-dimensional-vector?
        temp = []
        for j in range(0,numClass+1):

            # append a zero to the vector?
            temp.append(0)

        # append the vector to a vector??
        mat1.append(temp)
```

(...)

I am a little confused because in the pdf there are no explicit variable declarations. However I think and hope I could guess the variables.

Comment: you are right with your comment, however this code is really not so Pythonic.

Comment: In Python we do not declare variables like in Java/C#. It's a dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the method append() adds elements to the end of the list. I think your interpretation of the code is correct.

But note the following:

```
x =[1,2,3,4]
x.append(5)
print(x)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

while

```
x.append([6,7])
print(x)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, 7]]
```

If you want something like

```
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

you may use extend()

```
x.extend([6,7])
print(x)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to extend vs += ?

Comment: @Random832 Sry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: The big difference is that `extend` is a method of the `list` type, while `+=` works with any class that implements `__iadd__`. I think `extend` predates the introduction of `__iadd__`. Prior to that, `i+=something` where `i` wasn't built-in was the same as `i=i+something`, which resulted in a necessary temporary object for `i+something` that was then assigned to `i` (i.e., you couldn't modify the object referenced by `i` in-place).

Comment: @PhillipD as in `x += [6, 7]`.

Comment: @Random832 Now I understand your question (also based on chepner's comment). While both methods work, I don't know if there is a real practical advantage for one of the approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have explicit variable declarations. It's dynamically typed, variables are whatever type they get assigned to.

Your assessment of the code is pretty much correct.

One detail: The `range` function goes up to, but does not include, the last element. So the `+1` in the second argument to `range` causes the last iterated value to be `len(dataList)` and `numClass`, respectively. This looks suspicious, because the range is zero-indexed, which means it will perform a *total* of `len(dataList) + 1` iterations (which seems suspicious).

Presumably `dataList.sort()` modifies the original value of `dataList`, which is the traditional behavior of the `.sort()` method.

It is indeed appending the new vector to the initial one, if you look at the full source code there are several blocks that continue to concatenate more vectors to `mat1`.

Answer (score 1):

append is a list function used to append a value at the end of the list

mat1 and temp together are creating a 2D array (eg = [[], [], []]) or matrix of (m x n) 
where m = len(dataList)+1 and n = numClass

the resultant matrix is a zero martix as all its value is 0.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, variables are implicitely declared. When you type this:

```
i = 1
```

`i` is set to a value of `1`, which happens to be an integer. So we will talk of `i` as *being an integer*, although `i` is only a reference to an integer value. The consequence of that is that you don't need type declarations as in C++ or Java.

Your understanding is mostly correct, as for the comments. `[]` refers to a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). You can think of it as a linked-list (although its actual implementation is closer to `std::vector`s for instance).

As Python variables are only references to objects in general, `list`s are effectively lists of references, and can potentially hold any kind of values. This is valid Python:

```
# A vector of numbers
vect = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

But this is perfectly valid code as well:

```
# The list of my objects:
list = [1, [2,"a"], True, 'foo', object()]
```

This list contains an integer, another list, a boolean... In Python, you usually rely on [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) for your variable types, so this is not a problem.

Finally, one of the methods of `list` is `sort`, which sorts it in-place, as you correctly guessed, and the `range` function generates a range of numbers.

The syntax `for x in L: ...` iterates over the content of `L` (assuming it is iterable) and sets the variable `x` to each of the successive values in that context. For example:

```
>>> for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
...     print x
a
b
c
```

Since range generates a range of numbers, this is effectively the idiomatic way to generate a `for i = 0; i < N; i += 1` type of loop:

```
>>> for i in range(4): # range(4) == [0,1,2,3]
...     print i
0
1
2
3
```